# What are the rules regarding comment migration?

Tags: discussion, comments, migration

A question that I had commented on was moved from SO to DBA.SE.  In the process, it seems that 4 out of 5 existing comments migrated as well.  The exception was my highly rated comment, which happened to be the 2nd comment (not the first or last) and may be the only one that was edited.  Why would this be?

- Original on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300813/sql-server-worse-performance-on-a-new-server?noredirect=1
- Migrated to DBA.SE: [Worse performance on a new server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41223/sql-server-worse-performance-on-a-new-server)

I believe I'm a member on both sites.

**UPDATE**

I have since added the same comment (w/o the DBA.SE link) to the migrated question.

Comment: The only thing I can see is that you're the one who suggested the migration... Perhaps your comment was deleted automatically because of that? The algorithm must have thought "operation complete, this comment is no longer necessary".

Comment: That's because you mentioned/linked to DBA.SE. The heuristic figured you where talking about migrating, and so removed it.

Comment: @M.Night: You should place that as an answer.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby interesting...I had provided too much info by providing the link!

Comment: The same thing happens if you comment with a link to another question,  which the first question then gets closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: This is a harmful feature then. It should be turned off.

Comment: A relevant feature-request: [Don't automatically delete comments with useful content on migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279510/335251) (It starts: "When a question is migrated, any comment that mentions the name of the target site is automatically deleted. This makes sense when the comment is “you should have posted on <site>”, but comments that also contain other useful information [...] also get deleted.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you mentioned/linked to DBA.SE. The heuristic thought you where talking about migrating, and so removed it.